# What core is running my process?

Tags: linux, parallel-processing

I am currently taking a parallel programming class and our first programming exercise was to create four threads that displayed a "hello world" kinda of message. I would like to know what cores are running the threads.
I have tried using the TOP command on Unix to display all processes and I do see the 5 different threads, but not sure how to see what cores are running each thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Field j of top, `P`, shows you which core the thread/process last ran on.